# Is there a way to move forwarded emails back to the original Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-workspace

I have been forwarding emails from my university-based Gmail account to my personal Gmail account for years, and there are no copies of the emails in the original Gmail account. Now I graduated and I want to move these already read emails back to the original account so that they do not take 10GB space in my personal Google account space. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to delete them? If you can move them back, and you lose access to the university gmail account, then they will be gone.

Comment: No it is guaranteed that I will never lose access to the university account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch emails with the new (or old one) Gmail account do the same procedure:

> ```
> Log into your new Gmail account.
> Hit the gear icon.
> Select 'Settings'.
> Go to the 'Accounts and import' tab.
> Go to the 'Check mail from other accounts' section.
> Select 'Add a mail account'.
> Enter your old Gmail account and hit 'Next'.
> ```

[source](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aitl)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think this will move my personal emails as well to the university account, which I don't want. Right?

Comment: You can filter mails with tags, or delete after transfer.

Comment: If you are going to do this make sure you "Leave a copy of retrieved message on the server." otherwise all the mail will be moved.